# Make folders for albums in Google Photos

Tags: google-photos

I have one question regarding Google Photos. I have photos organised in albums, e.g.: Album 1, Album2, Album3.

Is there any way to put them into some folders? For example:

Folder 1

- Album 1
- Album 2

Folder 2

- Album 3

This would improve organisation of my Google Photos a lot.

Comment: Personally I just name my albums what I'm interested in and then I can use the search tool. I very rarely scroll to find my albums.

Answer (score 3):

No, I'm afraid that there's no way to nest photo albums in Google Photos.

The best option you have for organization is changing the name so that when the albums sort by name the ones you want will be "clustered" together.